# Board and batten on warped wall - best way to install?

Tags: walls, interior

When preparing to install board and batten on my wall, I found that the center of my 6' wall span is "warped" away from me, about 1/2" where I want the top rail, and 1/4" on the bottom rail. What's my easiest move here? Shim where needed and hope that caulk fills the gaps? Getting the vertical pieces will probably be a chore regardless.

[image: TopAndBottom]

[image: Top Rail]

[image: Bottom rail]

Comment: Assuming that the boards are on the same plane vertically, attach the battens to the boards and allow the battens to "float" along the wall. If needed, put a spacer block at the centerline to support the battens.